# AWS with ionic framework

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I will developing an app in ionic framework, and i use AWS S3 to store picture and documentation , what is the best used databases Amazon DynamoDB or mongodb ? and what the best way to connect AWS S3 with databases ?

finally i want app working in offline and online .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AWS Mobile Hub](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/) to serve as your project in AWS. You can use this service to create User Files which does exactly what you are describing for the users and provides tutorials on how to accomplish this.

I would download the AWS Mobile CLI and follow the steps to create your Mobile Hub Project from within your Ionic project root folder.

From there you can then start adding backend features to your app such as S3 for user files, pictures etc..

I would then head over to [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/index.html) and go through their set up tutorial for the Ionic frame work and then you can use Amplifies very easy to use functions right in your components to get and set data.

I just finished a mobile app with these and I can say it was a very easy process once going through the documentation.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, Do you have some tutorial to help me ?